# ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'calendario.models.Compras'>": "Parcelamento.compras" must be a "Compras" instance

Tags: python, django

Eu estou tentando criar uma tabela de parcelas, no qual o usuário irá informar o valor da compra, entrada (caso tenha), a quantidade de parcelas e a data da compra.
Com esses dados tenho que pegar a data de compra e mostrar as datas que o usuário deverá pagar.

Primeiro Problema - Não estou conseguindo colocar no BD o parcelamento pois gera o erro ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'calendario.models.Compras'>": "Parcelamento.compras" must be a "Compras" instance..

Segundo problema - Não tenho ideia de como colocar a lista de datas no BD.

meu models.py:

```
class Compras(models.Model):
    nome_compra = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    valor_compra = models.FloatField()
    entrada = models.FloatField()
    data_compra = models.DateField()
    tipo_parcelamento = models.IntegerField()
    quantidade_parcelas = models.IntegerField()
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_compra


class Parcelamento(models.Model):
    compras = models.ForeignKey(Compras, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    valor_parcela = models.FloatField()
    data_parcelas = models.DateField()
```

No meu utils.py

```
def gravar_dados(**kwars):
    nome_compra, valor_compra, entrada, data_compra, tipo_parcelamento, quantidade_parcelas = kwars.values()
    Compras.objects.create(nome_compra=nome_compra,
                           valor_compra=valor_compra,
                           entrada=entrada,
                           data_compra=data_compra,
                           tipo_parcelamento=tipo_parcelamento,
                           quantidade_parcelas=quantidade_parcelas,
                           )

    valor_parcela = (valor_compra - entrada) / quantidade_parcelas
    Parcelamento.objects.create(compras=Compras,
                                valor_compra=valor_parcela,
                                data_parcelas=,
                                )
```

onde nesse data_parcela, era para pegar as datas que eu tenho que calcular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quanto a sua primeira dúvida, na sua função de gravar os dados você não guarda em uma variável o objeto da compra que criou, então na linha que está criando o Parcelamento você está enviando a sua Classe de model "Compras". Para que consiga realizar o relacionamento entra as duas classes seu código deveria apresentar:

```
nova_compra = Compras.objects.create(nome_compra=nome_compra,...)
Parcelamento.objects.create(compras=nova_compra,
                                valor_compra=valor_parcela,
                                data_parcelas=,
                                )
```

O Django retorna ao utilizar o `objects.create` o objeto que você acabou de criar, incluindo sua chave (id) que você então passa pra o parcelamento, por meio dessa variável `nova_compra`.

Dito isso, acho que há uma maneira melhor de pensar esse código, sem que haja necessidade de uma model Parcelamento, sem salvar as parcelas no seu banco de dados.

Acho que você pode criar um método dentro da classe de Compras que já faça esse cálculo e retorne as parcelas, segue exemplo de como fazer isso caso as parcelas sejam iguais e tenham que ser pagas mensalmente (não sei o que é a variável tipo_parcelamento então vou ficar devendo essa parte):

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

class Compras(models.Model):
    nome_compra = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    valor_compra = models.FloatField()
    entrada = models.FloatField()
    data_compra = models.DateField()
    tipo_parcelamento = models.IntegerField()
    quantidade_parcelas = models.IntegerField()
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    @property
    def valor_parcela(self):
        valor_parcelado = self.valor_compra - self.entrada
        return valor_parcelado / self.quantidade_parcelas

    def data_parcelas(self):
        nextmonth = self.data_compra + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
        parcelas_info = {}
        for x in range(1, self.quantidade_parcelas + 1):
            parcelas_info[i] = nextmonth
            nextmonth = nextmonth + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
        return parcelas_info
```

Dessa forma, ao criar uma compra você pode acessar a data de cada parcela da seguinte forma:

```
nova_compra = Compras.objects.create(nome_compra=nome_compra,...)
data_parcelas = nova_compra.data_parcelas()

for numero_da_parcela in data_parcelas:
    data_parcelas[numero_da_parcela]
```

Você consegue então acessar qual é o número daquela parcela, a data em que ela ocorrerá, e por meio do `nova_compra.valor_parcela` o valor de cada parcela.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, nossa chega me deu uma animada sua resposta, estarei mudando meu codigo para realizar as alterações que você me passou.

Muito obrigado mesmo

So respondendo sua pergunta com relação a variavél tipo_parcelamento, qdo o usuário informar terá 3 tipos de parcelamento, diário (entrada + 1 parcela), quinzenal (15 dias para pagar) e o mensal (o padrão), ai vou calcular as prestações em cima desse informação.